# Glassfish is executing code from another project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

i'm working on a project using java EE and glassfish and for whatever reason whenever i deploy my project i get exception about an older project i was working on before. I have closed the previous project but just to make sure but it still happens.

The project i'm working on is called "DAE_PROJECT" and the previous is ACADEMIC_MANAGEMENT", on both these projects i have a ConfigBean which runs on startup which populates the DB and it is from this populate that the exceptions are comming. I guess because they have the same name glassfish is mixing them up.

I'm geting the following errors:

```
Info:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258
Info:   /file:/D:/Google_Drive/IPL/3º Ano/1º Semestre/Desenvolvimento de Aplicações Empresariais/AcademicManagement_Final/dist/gfdeploy/AcademicManagement/AcademicManagement-ejb_jar/_AcademicManagement-ejbPU login successful
Warning:   Failed to find MBean Server: null or empty List returned from MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null)
Warning:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'COURSES' does not exist.
Error Code: 30000
Call: SELECT CODE, NAME FROM COURSES WHERE (CODE = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="readCourse" referenceClass=Course sql="SELECT CODE, NAME FROM COURSES WHERE (CODE = ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
```

As  you can see the error comes from the previous project "ACADEMIC_MANAGEMENT"

I apreciate whatever help you can spare.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't undeployed your old application. Run the command

```
/path/to/glassfish/bin/asadmin undeploy AcademicManagement
```

If the errors still persist then you can undeploy it manually on the server,  it will be under `/path/to/glassfish/domains/{DOMAIN_NAME}/applications`.